# Is RFM9x LoRa Radio Module considered as LoRaWAN end-node?

Tags: lora

I made the RFM96 LoRa Radio Module by adafruit communicate to each other. The next step I want to do is connect to it to a gateway, which is either the [RAK7371 Developer Base](https://docs.rakwireless.com/Product-Categories/WisGate/RAK7271-7371/Quickstart/#prerequisites) or [RAK2287 Concentrator Module](https://docs.rakwireless.com/Product-Categories/WisLink/RAK2287/Quickstart/#what-do-you-need). After connecting these gateways to The Things Network (TTN), I noticed that it doesn't get or reflect the data from the RFM96 module in the gateway. I didn't see the data I sent using the module.

After doing researches, I may have found out what might be the reason -- RFM96 LoRa Radio Module is not considered as LoRaWAN end-node as needed by the gateways.

I would like to confirm to you and hoping that someone can shed light on this matter.

Thank you!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

LoRa and LoRaWAN are not the same.

[What are LoRa and LoRaWAN?](https://www.thethingsnetwork.org/docs/lorawan/what-is-lorawan/) tells you the details: -

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! Actually I already registered my RFM96 radio module to the TTN. However, I didn't see the data it sends. This what I got every time I open the serial monitor of my Arduino IDE.

Starting
Packet queued
1843: EV_JOINING
2122: EV_TXSTART
FAILURE

May I humbly ask for any insights I could take to address this? Thank you so much.

Comment: Honestly I have no idea.